# I'm attempting to return a "not found" result from a test that requires an object as an argument. Is there a way to do this gracefully?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

More context to my prompt: I'm designing an event reservation microservice for a school project with Spring-boot and using Mockito for testing. I'm currently running into an issue in my unit tests where I'm writing a failing test when attempting to retrieve a city.

In my other tests, the arguments are Strings where I'm able to simply return "not found", like so:

```
    @Test
    public void testDeleteCountryNotFound() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(countryRepository.findById(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        Mockito.when(countryRepository.existsById(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(false);
        Mockito.doThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class)
                .when(countryRepository)
                .deleteById(Mockito.any());

        assertFalse(countryService.deleteCountry("notfound"));
    }
```

However, the next series of tests requires objects called "CityId" as arguments (eg. `getCity(CityId cityId)`). I'm not sure how to return "not found" since the method I'm calling requires a `cityId` argument. Here's the code for the test and the method I'm testing:

```
    @Test
    public void testGetCityNotFound() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(cityRepository.findById(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());

        assertEquals(null,
                //need to find a way to return "not found" with cityId object
                cityService.getCity("notfound"));
    }
```

```
    public City getCity(CityId cityId) {
        try {
            return cityRepository.findById(cityId).get();
        } catch(NoSuchElementException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Is there an argument I can put into `cityService.getCity();` that will allow me to return a "not found" string?

EDIT: The object "CityId" is constructed like so:
`CityId(String countryCode, String postalCode)`

To clarify, I'm trying to get the string "not found" to result from calling `assertEquals(null, cityService.getCity(//"not found"));`

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. 
You want to have the getCity method return a string instead of a City, but only in the mock?

Comment: What? You need to pass in a `CityId` (whatever that is). And the way your tests are set up it doesn't matter what `CityId` you pass in because you mock the underlyig `findById`.

Comment: I should have specified the parameters for ```CityId```, my bad. It's constructed like ```CityId(String countryCode, String postalCode)```. But I'll give your suggestion a shot, thank you.

Comment: It is a little bit unusual to mock the repository and also mock the service as the repository usually sits behind the service. But if mocking both is necessary: Do something similar with cityService as you've done with cityRepository.